# how to change circle color when click on div?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have 4 div that when hover each of them `background-color` change to some color. now I want when click each of them change color of a circle with SVG tag. my codes are below:

```css
#a1,
#a2,
#a3,
#a4 {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#a1:hover {
  background-color: orangered;
}

#a2:hover {
  background-color: green;
}

#a3:hover {
  background-color: blue;
}

#a4:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:25%; margin:auto; text-align:center;">
  <div id="a1"></div>
  <div id="a2"></div>
  <div id="a3"></div>
  <div id="a4"></div>
</div>

<svg id="b" height="100" width="100">
   <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40"  />
</svg>
```

Can I do this just with CSS?? because I don't want use JavaScript or JQuery...

Comment: How do you think to make click event without javascript, or jQuery?

Comment: It can be done with just html and css with some tricks ...see the answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with a little bit of tricks using radio button 
basically you link the circle color to the checked radio button

```
#a1:checked~svg circle {
  /*the style here will apply when the radio button with id = a1 is checked */
}
```

see the code bellow:

```css
#l1,
#l2,
#l3,
#l4 {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#l1:hover {
  background-color: orangered;
}

#l2:hover {
  background-color: green;
}

#l3:hover {
  background-color: blue;
}

#l4:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.check-btn input {
  display: none;
}

#a1:checked~svg circle {
  fill: orangered;
}

#a2:checked~svg circle {
  fill: green;
}

#a3:checked~svg circle {
  fill: blue;
}

#a4:checked~svg circle {
  fill: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="check-btn">

  <input id="a1" type="radio" name="color">
  <label id="l1" for="a1" class="clicker"></label>
  <input id="a2" type="radio" name="color">
  <label id="l2" for="a2" class="clicker"></label>
  <input id="a3" type="radio" name="color">
  <label id="l3" for="a3" class="clicker"></label>
  <input id="a4" type="radio" name="color">
  <label id="l4" for="a4" class="clicker"></label>

  <svg id="b" height="100" width="100">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

## CSS-only solution

*(using the checkbox (well, radio button in this case) hack)*

```css
[name='c'] {
 position: absolute;
 right: 100%
}

#black:checked ~ svg circle { fill: black }
#purple:checked ~ svg circle { fill: purple }
#hotpink:checked ~ svg circle { fill: hotpink }
#orange:checked ~ svg circle { fill: orange }
```

```html
<input type='radio' name='c' id='black' checked/>
<input type='radio' name='c' id='purple'/>
<input type='radio' name='c' id='hotpink'/>
<input type='radio' name='c' id='orange'/>

<div style='width:25%; margin:auto; text-align:center;'>
 <div id='a1'><label for='black'>black</div>
 <div id='a2'><label for='purple'>purple</div>
 <div id='a3'><label for='hotpink'>hotpink</div>
 <div id='a4'><label for='orange'>orange</div>
</div>

<svg id='b' height='100' width='100'>
 <circle cx='50' cy='50' r='40'  />
</svg>
```

That being said, a pure CSS solution doesn't always mean the best solution.

---

## Simple JS solution:

```js
const _C = document.querySelector('circle');

addEventListener('click', e => {
 const _T = e.target;
 
 if(_T.id.match(/a[1-4]/)) {
  _C.setAttribute('fill', _T.textContent)
 }
}, false);
```

```html
<div style='width:25%; margin:auto; text-align:center;'>
 <div id='a1'>black</div>
 <div id='a2'>purple</div>
 <div id='a3'>hotpink</div>
 <div id='a4'>orange</div>
</div>

<svg id='b' height='100' width='100'>
 <circle cx='50' cy='50' r='40'  />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use Javascript. Here is a way you can do it:

```
<div id="colorOptions" style="width:25%; margin:auto; text-align:center;">
        <div class="item" id="a1"></div>
        <div class="item" id="a2"></div>
        <div class="item" id="a3"></div>
        <div class="item" id="a4"></div>
    </div>

    <svg id="b" height="100" width="100">
        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" />
    </svg>
```

**JQUERY:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var color;

  $("#colorOptions .item").click(function(){
    color = $(this).css("backgroundColor");
    $("#b circle").css("fill", color);
  })

})
```